# replaceAll и обратные слэши

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Сегодня занимался в Java проблемой кавычек в SQL запросах (инъекция) и обнаружил, что чтобы после результата функции получить `\'`, я должен написать следующее:

```java
String key = entry.getKey().replaceAll("'", "\\\\\\\\\'");
```

```sql
/*Оригинальная строчка*/
UPDATE t1 SET A' = '1' WHERE A = 'firefly';
```

```sql
/*Результат функции*/
UPDATE t1 SET A\' = '1' WHERE A = 'firefly';
```

Если я напишу просто `\\'`, по вернется простая `'`. Почему такое происходит? Я проверил с помощью `System.out.println('\\');`, где консоль мне вернула `\`, то есть верный результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для простой замены одного конкретного символа на пару других регулярные выражения не требуются, используйте [`String#replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
String result = text.replace("'", "\\'");
```

Если же всё-таки нужно заменить совпадение регулярного выражения каким-то буквальным текстом, без шаблонов, местозаполнителей, обратных ссылок и т.д. воспользуйтесь методом [`Matcher.quoteReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement-java.lang.String-), который экранирует всё, что нужно в шаблоне замены (не путайте с [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-)!):

```
String result = text.replaceAll("'", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\'"));
```

**Зачем нужно экранировать `$` и `\` в шаблоне замены?** Эти символы используются для задания специальных конструкций в шаблоне замены. `\` (буквальный символ, `"\\"` в строковом литерале Java) является экранирующим символом `$`, а `$` с последующим за ним числом формирует обратную ссылку на значение соответствующей захватывающей подмаски.

[Пример кода](https://ideone.com/SrqL4C):

```
import java.util.regex.*; 
// ...
String dano = "UPDATE t1 SET A' = '1' WHERE A = 'firefly';";
System.out.println(dano.replace("'", "\\'")); 
// => UPDATE t1 SET A\' = \'1\' WHERE A = \'firefly\';
System.out.println(dano.replaceAll("'", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\'")));
// => UPDATE t1 SET A\' = \'1\' WHERE A = \'firefly\';
```

Answer (score 1):

Читай документацию

> Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see `Matcher.replaceAll`. Use `Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)` to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

[Документация replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))